# Multiple Nodes with same Name in SOAP Call

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

Am trying to call an API. The XML I needed is follows.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:ConversionRate/>
    <param1>
        <MessageTitle>Some Title</MessageTitle>
        <Images>
            <Image>http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gzGWCfqJr_k/T-B7L0wlwSI/AAAAAAAADkw/C7sznAKVktc/s1600/rose_flower_screensaver-234027-1240456558.jpeg</Image>
            <Image>http://img.ehowcdn.com/article-new-thumbnail/ehow/images/a07/tv/vu/object-property-names-array-php-800x800.jpg</Image>
        </Images>
    </param1>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to pass multiple images in     tags. But I can only pass only one item. In php multi dimentional array doesnot support same key. My php code

```
 $client = new    SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl',        array(  'trace'      => true, 'exceptions' => true,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1 ) );
    try {

        $data_params = new stdClass();
        $imgs = new stdClass();

        $img1 = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gzGWCfqJr_k/T-B7L0wlwSI/AAAAAAAADkw/C7sznAKVktc/s1600/rose_flower_screensaver-234027-1240456558.jpeg';
        $img2 = 'http://img.ehowcdn.com/article-new-thumbnail/ehow/images/a07/tv/vu/object-property-names-array-php-800x800.jpg';

        $imgs->Image = $img1;

        $data_params->MessageTitle                =    'Some Title';
        $data_params->Images                     =       $imgs;        

        $params    =    array(    'Id' => '187',
                    'Data'=>$data_params);

        $result = $client->__soapCall('ConversionRate',$params);
        echo $client->__getLastRequest();
    }catch(SoapFault $exception)
    {
            var_dump($exception);
            echo $client->__getLastRequest();
    }
```

Comment: You must confuse the webservice here, there aren't such parameter image URLs anywhere - see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19745107/367456 it just works.

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like

```
   <Images>
    <Image>
    <item>your Image<item>
    </Image>
    <Image>
    <item>your 2nd Image<item>
    </Image>
    </Images>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must absolutely have confused something, the CurrencyConvertor webservice ConversionRate method in question works just fine and does not have any duplicate parameter names, only duplicate types, but those are strings - and not image URLs.

Here is the output of the working code (ConversionRate from EUR to USD):

```
class stdClass#2 (1) {
  public $ConversionRateResult =>
  double(1.3488)
}
```

Here is the working code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Multiple Nodes with same Name in SOAP Call
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/19727338/367456
 */

$wsdl    = 'http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl';
$options = array(
    'trace'        => true,
    'exceptions'   => true,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

$params = array(
    'FromCurrency' => 'EUR',
    'ToCurrency'   => 'USD',
);

var_dump(
    $client->ConversionRate($params)
);
```